# Merge range of cells offset to target

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where Appt Note text is very lengthy. I need to place it in a row of nine merged cells.

I'm trying to check all the cells in column A for the value "Appt Note:" then merge the nine cells to the right of it so all my data shows up in a viewable format.

I checked lots of posts online but can't put my particular code together. I've built it, with the exception of the merge.

```
Sub MergeTest()
Dim cel As Range
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In Worksheets
    For Each cel In WS.Range("$A1:$A15")
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Appt Note:") > 0 Then Range(cel.Offset(1, 9)).Merge
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `cel.Resize(1, 9).Merge`

Comment: Note that merging cells will discard the information in all but the top, left most cell in the range.

Comment: Is this value just in a single cell? If so, you could do without the loop and use `Range.Find`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you.  I tried the cel.Resize code but that merge includes column A.  I do not want to include column A in my merge.  If column A contains the text "Appt Note:" then I want it to merge the cells in columns B through J in the same row.  Currently I have the label in column A and all the text I need merged in column B.
Also I plan on making this logic trigger on a change in the spreadsheet once I get it to work so I need all message window suppressed as this will be processed via a script that will not have manual intervention available while running.

Thank you!!!!

Comment: @JvdV could you give me an example on how to use Range.Find?  The data I want to merge is housed in a single cell but it may be found anywhere in column B of my spreadsheet and I need to find and merge every instance.

Comment: `cel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 9).Merge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, hereby a sample of `Range.Find` where in this case I assume `"Appt Note:"` only exists once per sheet:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cl As Range

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set cl = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:="Appt Note:", Lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not cl Is Nothing Then
        cl.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 9).Merge
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

**Note:** Merged cells are VBA's worst nightmare! Try to stay away from them. Maybe you can let the text just overflow?

---

Edit: In case your value could exist multiple times, use `Range.FindNext`:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cl As Range
Dim rw As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set cl = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:="Appt Note:", Lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not cl Is Nothing Then
        rw = cl.Row
        Do
            cl.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 9).Merge
            Set cl = ws.Range("A:A").FindNext(cl)
        If cl Is Nothing Then
            GoTo DoneFinding
        End If
        Loop While cl.Row <> rw
    End If
DoneFinding:
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, it is helpful.  However, "Appt Note:" exists multiple times throughout column A in which I need to merge the corresponding cells to the right.  I would need the code to loop and search until it finds them all.

Comment: Then use .FindNext =)

Comment: LOL I gave it a shot.  I tried updating the code to add the FindNext process but failed miserably.  Can you help me fix it?

    Sub MergeCells2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cl As Range

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set cl = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:="Appt Note:", Lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not cl Is Nothing Then
        cl.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 9).Merge
        Set cl = .FindNext(cl)
    If cl Is Nothing Then
        GoTo DoneFinding
    End If
    Loop While Not cl Is Nothing
    End If
Next
DoneFinding:
End Sub

Sorry I wasn't able to format my comment nice

Comment: Maybe tomorrow, it's midnight here :)

Comment: YIKES!!! OK, thanks good night!  Link to my updated code below so you can view it nicer.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkG2AFfuqFVWpkKfiVJVvw0itoqn?e=US1BQa

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MergeTest()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A15")
            If cell.Value Like "Appt Note:*" Then cell.Resize(1, 9).Merge
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

`ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook where the VBA code is, to avoid issues when a different workbook is active. The [`Like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) can be used to check if the cell value matches a wildcard pattern.
`cell.Resize(1, 9)` can be used to get a new range starting from `cell` and resized to 9 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I found code that will do what I need.  See below. I've tested it and it works.  It will start at the bottom of my spreadsheet and find the last row with data and work it's way up until it reaches my first row.

Thanks so much for all your help!  If you have any suggestions, advice, warnings, etc regarding the code below, please share.  As I said, I am completely new to VB and know just enough to be dangerous.  So I can use all the help I can get. :)

```
 Sub mergeCellsBasedOnCriteria()
Dim myFirstRow As Long
Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim myCriteriaColumn As Long
Dim myFirstColumn As Long
Dim myLastColumn As Long
Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim myCriteria As String
Dim iCounter As Long

myFirstRow = 1
myCriteriaColumn = 1
myFirstColumn = 2
myLastColumn = 10
myCriteria = "Appt Note:"

Set myWorksheet = Worksheets("Sample")

With myWorksheet

    myLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For iCounter = myLastRow To myFirstRow Step -1
        If .Cells(iCounter, myCriteriaColumn).Value = myCriteria Then
            .Range(.Cells(iCounter, myFirstColumn), .Cells(iCounter, myLastColumn)).Merge
            .Range(.Cells(iCounter, myFirstColumn), .Cells(iCounter, myLastColumn)).WrapText = True

        End If
    Next iCounter

End With
```

End Sub

Comment: You are looping all cells which is unnecessary.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks, can you help me modify the code so I don't have to loop through every cell?  I need it to find each cell that contains the text I'm looking for and merge the corresponding cells in the same row.